# How to find the number occurences of elements of a two-dimensional array, read from a file?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I have a problem with Array.count method on a two-dimensional array.

I load my two-dimensional array from have a file where I have stored before, something like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I made this class called Maps:

```
require 'json'
class Maps 

  def initialize(filename)
    @map = JSON.parse(File.read(filename))
  end

  def isCorrupted?
    @map.count(0) > 1 ? true : false
  end

end
```

and when I try to use my class method isCorrupted? the result it's always false.

```
require_relative 'classes/maps'

current_map = Maps.new("test.txt")
puts current_map.isCorrupted?
```

I don't understand why the method doesn't find the two *0* in the ten sub-array and return **FALSE**.

I also try to modify the method to get the count occurrences, like this:

```
@map.count(0)
```

but the result it's always **0**.

Can someone help me? I need to know the total number of ZERO in the global array.

Edit-2: Flatten was what I need.

Comment: If zero anywhere makes a model corrupted, `@map.flatten.count(0)` should work.

Comment: The answers show that your question is not clear. Is the data "corrupted" if at least one of the elements (arrays) of your array contains two or more zeros or if the flattened array contains two or more zeros? Please clarify with an edit (even though you have selected an answer, considering that your question may be read by many others in future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your code doesn't work the way you intend it to cause you are trying to count `0` elements in the collection of arrays (not integers).

In case you need to know if there are more than two zeroes in all subarrays in total:

```
@map.flatten.count(0) > 1
```

In case you want to know if there are subarrays that include one or more zeroes you should use another approach:

```
@map.any? { |collection| collection.count(0) > 1 }
```

Comment: IT'S WORKS! So Flatten transform a multi-dimensional array into a mono-dimensional array, right? Thank you so much

Comment: `@map.flatten.count(0) > 1 ? true : false` is redundant and confusing. `@map.flatten.count(0) > 1` already returns a boolean.

Comment: @Nifriz Yes. And if you provide an optional argument (e.g. `@map.flatten(1)`), then it will only flatten it by "1 level", rather than the default of "unlimited levels" (i.e always flatten down to 1-dimension). See the documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten

Comment: Actually, thinking about it... Shouldn't that be `> 0`, or `>= 1`? If `> 1` really is the correct logic, then this `flatten` simplification doesn't work. Your original code was checking whether **two or more** `0`s appear in a **single row**, whereas this version is checking whether **two or more** `0` appear in the **all rows combined**. That's not the same thing.

Comment: As per @mudasobwa's comment above: "If zero **anywhere** makes a model corrupted...."

Comment: @TomLord test is correct >1, I must know if there is more than 1 element coded as ZERO

Answer (score 3):

Using `flatten` does not work here.

Doing so would be a valid *optimisation*, if the requirement was simply to check whether **any** `0` is present in the nested arrays. But that's not what you're doing here; you want to check that *more than one* `0` appears in any array.

For example, you want to consider the following as non-corrupt, but poashin's answer would consider it as corrupt:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Therefore, you should iterate through the arrays:

```
require 'json'

class Maps 
  def initialize(filename)
    @map = JSON.parse(File.read(filename))
  end

  def is_corrupted?
    @map.any? { |row| row.count(0) > 1 }
  end
end
```

(Minor point: I have followed the [ruby style guide conventions here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming), and used `snake_case` for the method name, not `camelCase`.)

Comment: I will follow convention, minor point biu important ;) About FLATTEN, it's works

Comment: As I said, flatten does **not** work for your use case. What do you expect the result of `is_corrupted?` to be, when the file contains `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`? My answer: `false`. Nifriz's answer: `true`.

Comment: You wanted to check whether there's more than one `0` in `[0,1]` or `[1,0]` -- which there isn't. Using `flatten` here will simply check whether there is more than one `0` in `[0, 1, 1, 0]` -- which there is. By my understanding of the question, that's not the right definition of `corrupted`.

Comment: I want to check if there are 2 or more "0" in all the arrays.  [0, 1, 1, 0] for me needed is corrupt ;)

Comment: Another Ruby style [convention](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#bool-methods-prefix) is not to prepend Boolean methods with `is_`, just append the `?`.

Comment: @Nifriz ‍♂️ I asked above for clarification, and I thought you said the opposite. Sigh. Well, in that case the original answer will work fine. But really, this is quite frustrating for me - it would have taken you 10 seconds to simply provide a [mcve] of the problem, like above (`[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`) and define your requirements clearly. You just said "two 0s in the sub-arrays", and your only example contained two `0`s in **one** sub-array, not spread between two different sub-arrays.